# What does FHQT or FQA mean?

Tags: index, full-text-search, database-theory, terminology

I was reading [this post by Andres Pascal](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Index-for-Levenshtein-distance-tp5764546p5768127.html), and I came accross a few new acronyms,

> As I understand, you need to search strings by similarity (using levenshtein or any other metric distance). In that case, you can use metric indexes like `FHQT` or `FQA` (this is better if you are using a relational database, like postgres). But they are not implemented yet in most DBMS, so you need to program the index. It s not too hard, but you need to understand the base concepts. You can look for "searching in metric spaces" to read about it. If you are in a hurry, you can mail me and maybe I can help you.

What exactly do those two acronyms means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Fixed Height Queries Tree (FHQT)**

  [*"Metric-Temporal Access Methods"*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228457576_Metric-Temporal_Access_Methods) we can find the first definition, as a somewhat interesting aside, one of the primary authors on that paper is Andres Pascal himself. Nice to know he's working on PostgreSQL.
- **Fixed Queries Array (FQA)**

  And in [*"Fixed Queries Array: A Fast and Economical Data Structure for Proximity Searching"*](https://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~gnavarro/ps/mtap01.pdf) in the title.

A rabbit hole to go down another time...